# AWS Athena isn't using partitions discovered by Glue crawler, while Redshift Spectrum is

Tags: amazon-redshift, parquet, aws-glue, partitioning, amazon-athena

I'm struggling with this, let me describe the scenario:

- I have a PySpark process running on EMR, which write a big table into S3, using parquet files.
- The table is written using hive like partitions, ie: `s3://my-bucket/my_table/date=2021-12-16/event=user_created`
- Then I run a Glue crawler that successfully detects all the partitions and create a table on my database: `my_database.my_table`
- Last, I have this database "mounted" on Redshift by creating an external database like this:

```sql
create external schema my_database
from data catalog
database 'my_database'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::blabla'
create external database if not exists;
```

So, If I run

```sql
select *
from my_database
where date = '2021-12-16'
and event = 'user_created'
limit 500;
```

On Redshift, this finishes in 5s and scans 20MB of data :heart:

but if I run **the exact same query** from the query editor in the Athena console it'll take some minutes to complete or even be aborted because it reached a limt of 25GB that we set.

What is going on here? Shouldn't Athena benefit from partitioning as well? I feel like I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT:
adding more info, thanks Theo
Here's the table schema, sorry for the blurred columns:
[image: table schema and partitions]
date is a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, I was using `year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD/` but resulted very difficult to query. Any other advice is welcomed.

Here's the output of three different explains **on Redshift Spectrum**

```sql
explain select * from datalake.mytable
```

[image: no filter]

```sql
explain select * from datalake.mytable
where event = 'a_valid_event'
```

[image: filter by event]

```sql
explain select * from datalake.mytable
where event = 'a_valid_event'
and "date" = '2021-12-14'
```

[image: filter by event and date]

Here's the output of the same queries ran on AWS Athena console:
[image: no filter in Athena]
note that this one took 3 minutes on explain! where spectrum took always less than 10s.

Output using only event filter
[image: only event filter Athena]

last output using event and date on Athena. This explain was blazing fast!
[image: explain with both partitions as filters on Athena. fastest]

I've added partition indexes to this table because sometimes people will query it using only one of the partitions set up, this is how it looks like (qq: adding `event_timestamp` index wasn't necessary at all, right?)
[image: partition indexes]

Additionally I'd like to say that I've tried the speed of different combinations of filters using boto3 glue client method `get_partitions`, and it's fetching all partitions just fine!

My own diagnosis is: Athena isn't using partition indexes at all, so if you use one ONE partition field in the filter (instead of the total two) it will just scan a lot of data.
Which would match what says here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/partition-indexes.html#partition-index-limitations

which is nonesense because filtering by event (partition) and then looking for one valid user_id (no partition) will hit the 25GB data scanned cap and abort.
[image: event and user_id aborts max scanned]

Comment: Can you share the table schema please? What are the data types of the partition keys? Can you also share the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_database …` when you run that in Athena?